# Combining plots with distinct legends

Tags: plot, visualization, wolfram-mathematica

First, sorry because I am very new to Mathematica, English and Stackoverflow. So, I have the following code:

```
k := (di^3 *dj*wi^2 + 2*di^2*(2 - dj)*wi*wj + 
     di*(2 - dj)*wj^2) / (4*di^2*wi + 4*(2 - dj) wj);
wi := 10;
wj := 9;

Table[Plot[
  Evaluate[f[b] /. 
    NDSolve[{f'[b] == 
       2*f[b]/(di*f[b] + 
           di^2*((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])/(di*
                 dj) + ((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])^2/(di*dj)^2 + (2 - 
                    dj)*(4*b - di*f[b])*f[b]/(di^3*dj))^(1/2) - 2*b)),
       f[0] == 10^-5}, f, {b, 0, k}]], {b, 0, k}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   StringTemplate["di = `a`, dj = `b`"][<|"a" -> di, "b" -> dj|>]],
 {dj, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1}, {di, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}];
```

and I want to combine the curves like that, all in one graphics

```
k := (di^3 *dj*wi^2 + 2*di^2*(2 - dj)*wi*wj + 
     di*(2 - dj)*wj^2) / (4*di^2*wi + 4*(2 - dj) wj);
wi := 10;
wj := 9;

Show[Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[
    f[b] /. NDSolve[{f'[b] == 
        2*f[b]/(di*f[b] + 
            di^2*((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])/(di*
                  dj) + ((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])^2/(di*dj)^2 + (2 - 
                    dj)*(4*b - di*f[b])*f[b]/(di^3*dj))^(1/2) - 2*b)),
        f[0] == 10^-5}, f, {b, 0, k}]], {b, 0, k}, PlotRange -> All],
  {dj, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1}, {di, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}]]
```

Can someone help me to put the legends like the graphics below?

```
RAveList = RandomReal[1, {11, 5}];
colors = ColorData[97];
labels = Row[{#, "-clusters"}] & /@ Range[2, 12];
ListPlot[Thread[Tooltip[RAveList, labels]], Joined -> True, 
 DataRange -> {0, 5}, PlotStyle -> colors, PlotLegends -> labels, 
 Axes -> None, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to include the output of each code.

Comment: By the way, there is a Stack Exchange forum dedicated to Mathematica here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 20 plots

```
range = Catenate[Table[{dj, di}, {dj, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1}, {di, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}]];
Length[range]
```

> 20

Find a range of 20 colours in ColorData

```
Column[Select[
  {#, Length[cols = ColorData[#, "ColorList"]], cols} & /@
   ColorData["Indexed"], #[[2]] >= 20 &]]
```

ColorData[54] will do.

```
colours = ColorData[54, #] & /@ Range[20];
```

Assign 20 colours to `f` for the various `{dj, di}`

```
MapThread[(f[#1] = #2) &, {range, colours}];
```

Add `PlotStyle` and `LineLegend` showing {*dj*, *di*}

```
GraphicsRow[{Show[Catenate[Table[Plot[Evaluate[f[b] /. NDSolve[
         {f'[b] == 2*f[b]/
             (di*f[b] + di^2*((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])/(di*dj) +
                  ((2*b - (2 - dj)*f[b])^2/(di*dj)^2 +
                    (2 - dj)*(4*b - di*f[b])*f[b]/
                    (di^3*dj))^(1/2) - 2*b)),
          f[0] == 10^-5}, f, {b, 0, k}]], {b, 0, k},
      PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> f[{dj, di}]],
     {dj, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1}, {di, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}]]],
  LineLegend[colours, range]}]
```

[image]

For a more visually ordered legend, listing according to the order as plotted.

```
ordered = Catenate[Reverse /@ Transpose[
     Table[{dj, di}, {dj, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1}, {di, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1}]]];

GraphicsRow[{Show[...],
  LineLegend[f /@ ordered, ordered]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very well! Thanks for that!